# Implementing List interface for CustomList in Java

Tags: java, list, interface, custom-lists

I need to create a custom list that adds elements in pairs. I copied a similar implementation and adjusted it as needed, but unfortunately, it doesn't work.

```
class PairStringList implements List<String> {

    private List list;

    public PairStringList() {
        list = new ArrayList();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean add(String s) {
        list.add(list.size(), s);
        list.add(list.size(), s);
        return true;
    }

//other methods
}
```

And I have this for testing my code so far.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> list = new PairStringList();
        list.add("1");
        list.add("2");
        list.add("3");

        for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            String s = list.get(i);
            System.out.println(s);
        }

        list.add(4, "0");

        for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(list.get(i));
        }
    }
```

The problem is that when I call add method the size of the list increases by 2 as it should, but nothing is added and I get an array full of nulls.

Comment: We need more information. Your `add()` method looks OK, so the problem is likely to be in your `size()` or `get()` method. Please show them to us, too. Sidenote: instead of `list.add(list.size(), s)` you can just do `list.add(s)`. Works the same, but is slightly more clear and simple.

Comment: I took your code and implemented `size()` as `return list.size();`, and `get()` as `return list.get(index)`, and that successfully prints out the pairs of 1s, 2s and 3s as expected. (Doesn't print out the 0s because I didn't implement `public void add(int index, String element)`, but that's expected).

Comment: Thank you so much. I have been staring at the code for so long and I didn't notice that my get method is not implemented. I feel stupid now.

Comment: Warning: you are using a raw type, i.e. `List`. **Never use raw types**, always provide the necessary type arguments, i.e. `List<String>`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must have to implement `get(int index)` method in your `PairStringList`. Currently your get method is simply returning `null`. Implementation of `get(int index)` method should be as shown below:

```
@Override
public String get(int index) {
    return list.get(index);
}
```